# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

This is my code:

```
Frame.gameController.test();
setContentView(Frame.world.getScreen());
Frame.world.setRunning(true);
```

On the second line I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15229): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Can anyone help me solve it? Previously it was working just fine, the problem starts when I take it in another activity.

I'm using android 2.2.

Comment: i am drawing on canvas, if it helps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use the same view in multiple activities. Instead you should create a new instance of the view.

Comment: can u give me an example, any link? to how to do it proper way?

Comment: @KISHORDATTAGUPTA it look like Frame.world.getScreen() is getting a shared instance. You should probably create a new instance instead.

Comment: An example for what? You gave us almost no code, no purposes. I just explained you the reasong you are getting the exception.

Comment: @emjam, thanks for explaining. but i very new in android ,so i dont understand how my only activity get shared.

Comment: You said you retrieved the view from another activity. Instead of retrieving the view you'd better inflate a new one. Or, maybe you don't need the second activity and should stick to a single activity. All depends on your task.

Comment: i have another activity, which i am not calling.in only activity i m running the view. if the first activity i call, i m going to get the error right?

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you are trying to set content from objects that already have parent. It looks like you set some views in one activity, for example:

```
TextView tv = new TextView();
layout.adView(tv);
layout2.adView(tv);
```

and that error appears when you try to add that tv to different layout. In your situation it's because Layout from one activity is trying to be set as a child in the other activity.

You have to release child from other parent first.