# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. List View

Tags: java, android, listview

my code for ListView getView function.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView; 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        if(view==null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.outgoingcall, null,false);
        }
        LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        layout.removeAllViews();
        layout.addView(mGraph.get(0), new LayoutParams(400, 700)); 
        return view;
    }
```

I am getting this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 20:44:12.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12378): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
06-27 20:44:12.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12378):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3351)
06-27 20:44:12.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12378):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3222)
06-27 20:44:12.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12378):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3202)
```

Comment: In which line you are getting the error? 
In this : layout.addView(mGraph.get(0), new LayoutParams(400, 700));  ?

Comment: yes  in this line only .
layout.addView(mGraph.get(0), new LayoutParams(400, 700));

Comment: I added these lines

ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup) layout.getParent();
  if(vg!=null){
  vg.removeView(layout);
  }

 after  
 LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
 but still same error I'm getting.

Comment: mmm, seems like the problem is in : "android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3202)", this means that mGraph.get(0) is already children of another view. 
So, try to remove mGraph from its parent and then add it to your layout with layout.addView(....

Comment: Here is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552990/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-m?rq=1